# OpenAI Gym equivalent for supervised and/or unsupervised learning

Tags: openai-gym

OpenAI Gym has really normalized the way reinforcement learning is performed. It makes it possible for data scientists to separate model development and environment setup/building and to focus on what they really should be focusing on.

Quoting from [Gym website](https://gym.openai.com/docs/):

> **Background: Why Gym? (2016)**
>
> Reinforcement learning (RL) is the subfield of machine learning
> concerned with decision making and motor control. It studies how an
> agent can learn how to achieve goals in a complex, uncertain
> environment. It’s exciting for two reasons:
>
> - **RL is very general, encompassing all problems that involve making a sequence of decisions**: for example, controlling a robot’s motors so
>   that it’s able to run and jump, making business decisions like pricing
>   and inventory management, or playing video games and board games. RL
>   can even be applied to supervised learning problems with sequential or
>   structured outputs.
> - **RL algorithms have started to achieve good results in many difficult environments**. RL has a long history, but until recent
>   advances in deep learning, it required lots of problem-specific
>   engineering. DeepMind’s Atari results, BRETT from Pieter Abbeel’s
>   group, and AlphaGo all used deep RL algorithms which did not make too
>   many assumptions about their environment, and thus can be applied in
>   other settings.
>
> However, RL research is also slowed down by two factors:
>
> - **The need for better benchmarks**. In supervised learning, progress has been driven by large labeled datasets like ImageNet. In RL, the
>   closest equivalent would be a large and diverse collection of
>   environments. However, the existing open-source collections of RL
>   environments don’t have enough variety, and they are often difficult
>   to even set up and use.
> - **Lack of standardization of environments used in publications**. Subtle differences in the problem definition, such as the reward
>   function or the set of actions, can drastically alter a task’s
>   difficulty. This issue makes it difficult to reproduce published
>   research and compare results from different papers.
>
> Gym is an attempt to fix both problems.

I was wondering if there is something equivalent for supervised or unsupervised learning. I believe such a tool will be useful for the same reasons. Am I missing something? Or is there there something already out there?

Answer (score 0):

One standard way to represent data for both supervised and unsupervised learning is the [tidy dataframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data). Tidy dataframe is putting data into tabular form where each row is an observation and each column is a feature. Once data is in that form, machine learning modeling can take place.